# how to send response only after mv library on nodejs completes. Wrapping in promise doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to setup an endpoint that takes a file through a multipart post request, and saves it into a specific directory using formidable and https://github.com/andrewrk/node-mv. And then upon completion of saving all of the files, I want to respond with a list of all of the files in that directory for rendering. the thing is the response seems to be sent before the directory listing is updated. I tried wrapping the mv operations into a promise and then responding in a then block to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
app.post("/api/v1/vendor/:id/menu", (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const form = formidable({ multiples: true, keepExtensions: true });
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(files.image)) {
      files = [files.image];
    }
    let filelist;
    const proms = files.map((file) => {
      const dst = `pics/${id}/${file.name}`;
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mv(file.path, dst, { mkdirp: true }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error("error: ", err.status);
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log("done moving");
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
    Promise.all(proms).then(() => {
      console.log('now reading dir...');
      filelist = fs.readdirSync("pics/" + id);
      res.send(filelist);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Instead of writing the logic inside .then(). Use [async/await][1] here. Whats happening in the above code is after line 3 it is returning immediately I believe.

Example: 

  [1]: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth I should have mentioned that I've tried async await as well. from my understanding, there's nothing functionally different from the two and it's purely syntactic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're missing the `return` keywork before `new Promise`. You can check the `proms` variable if it contains the list of promises or not.

```
const proms = files.map((file) => {
      const dst = `pics/${id}/${file.name}`;
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mv(file.path, dst, { mkdirp: true }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error("error: ", err.status);
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log("done moving");
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
```

For me, it should be :

```
const proms = files.map((file) => {
      const dst = `pics/${id}/${file.name}`;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mv(file.path, dst, { mkdirp: true }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error("error: ", err.status);
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log("done moving");
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
```